# Shutdown/reboot Raspberry using a pin other than pin 5

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

Is it possible to use another pin instead pin 5 (GPIO 3) to shutdown/reboot raspberry by means a push button?
Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi 4 B GPIO boot and shutdown button(s)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/117013/raspberry-pi-4-b-gpio-boot-and-shutdown-buttons)

Answer (score 1):

Yo

You can shutdown with any pin but only pin 5 can reboot, although there are dedicated non GPIO control pins which can reboot, depending on Pi model.

---

You can always use pin 5 to reboot, because this is handled by video core (unless the external connection affects the voltage level).

It is doubtful that you could also use it for shutdown as there is potential conflict.

See [Raspberry Pi 3 model B "dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77905/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-dtoverlay-gpio-shutdown/77918#77918)

Comment: Hi Milliways. Thanks for you reply. Because pin5 is used to connect my Pi to a thermal camera, do you think that could share it and use also to shutdown/restart Raspberry?