# File content disappears when Raspberry Pi is unplugged

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I tried to create a config file on my IoT device that is used for storing content when a user changes a setting via a menu. I found that every time the content of file is changed and then the system is unplugged, all of content in my config file disappears. This doesn't happen when I reboot or shutdown correctly but my device cannot avoid the user unplugging it without shutdown or reboot.

My Raspbian version is November 2016 Anyone know what I should do?

Comment: Your question is not containing any info, data or facts that make it comprehensible. So add more data, facts and info.

Comment: I have file Config.txt that contain this

DisplayBrightness=100

and them I change 100 to 60 via c++ program and remove plug off.
When I start my Rpi this content is disappeared and size of my Config.txt is zero.

However if type sudo reboot or sudo shutdown this line of content still there !!

Comment: Similar: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32146/read-write-filesystem-no-problem-when-halting-the-pi-by-removing-the-power-cor

Comment: Yes similar. Is there anyway to handle this without using RC circuit or install NARD ?

Comment: You should probably update Raspbian, and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand. You write a file to disk. When the device is shutdown. File is there. 
When device loose power ( ripp out the powerchorde) the file is gone. 
I'm not a cc+ programmer. But I believe this is due to not flushing file content to disk and closing the file pointer.  (In your application)
If you run shutdown/reboot. The OS will try to do the magic for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to flush my file from my application.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Some Combination of `sync`, `fsync`, `flush`**

---

Flash is slow, files are not immediately written to disk, unless you force the operation it may be longer than you expect.

In **shell**, **bash** use `sync`, a system call

> `sync` - synchronize data on disk with memory
>
> https://linux.die.net/man/2/sync
>
> https://linux.die.net/man/3/sync

**c**, **c++**, **python**, etc. you need to first `(f)flush` (after `write`). Some language structures have convenience methods for doing this (e.g. in c++
 [ostream::flush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/) )

> `fflush` - flush a stream
>
> https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush

and then `fsync` (or can also `sync` ) to write to disk

> `fsync`, `fdatasync` - synchronize a file's in-core state with storage device
>
> https://linux.die.net/man/3/fsync

**NOTE** Note that `flush` is called automatically on close file or if process quits, `sync` *is not*

Comment: I use fstream for file writing. Can I use flush instead of fflush ?

Comment: @3ORZ Yes, its the same thing (`fflush(file) == fstream.flush()`) fflush is the actual api call. Sync is more critical. Roughly speaking `flush` = write out to kernel buffer, `sync` = write out to disk.

Comment: I tried both flush and sync before fstream.close() and it doesn't work :(

Comment: close then sync.