# Safe cut power supply from raspberry

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, python, pi-zero

I want to cut safe the power supply from the raspberry with a relay
connected to the gpio. 
I know how to connect to relay to the board but..
When the relay turn off the power line will be cut off to quick 
before the system was completely shutdown.
does anyone know how to fix this ?

I need to cut off the powerline for my project because the PI is powered by a battery.

Thanks.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Possibly related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/5372/19949